# Does an HTTP request get cached when in the API ResponseCache NoStore = true? On a particular API endpoint

Tags: asp.net-core, httpresponsecache

I'm looking through this documentation: [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

What I read is that if response caching nostore attribute is set to true the server won't cache a response from that particular API endpoint. But what I'm wondering is what does it mean to Cache a response? I'm trying to figure out if this endpoint logs http request but is caching different then logging a request?

I'm trying to figure out if a webapp logs HTTP requests so I'm looking through my code but in the API I can only see that response caching nostore is set to true.

Some clarification would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ASP.net api or webservice old asmx type you can specify caching on method 
and when you call that method it can cache results.

Like suppose whenever any code calls an api get stockdata it goes to database and get data
you can apply caching on it.So when you call same method at 00:00 hr and 00:02 hr .The data will be same and it will not go to to database to fetch new value .

[Please check this](https://exceptionnotfound.net/a-simple-caching-scheme-for-web-api-using-dependency-injection/)